# Detect Time Out Error With AFNetworking

Tags: ios, objective-c, timeout, afnetworking

i use [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) to retrieve data from my web service every thing work perfectly, but i want to detect the time out error. I used this code in the failure block of the request but i don't work

```
failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    if ([operation.response statusCode] == 408) {
      //time out error here
    }
}];
```

The code 408 is normaly for the time out error

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Since AFNetworking is build on top on NSULConnection/NSULRSession you can just `NSURLErrorTimedOut` to check if the error is a timeout error:

```
 failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {

    if (error.code == NSURLErrorTimedOut) {
      //time out error here
    }
}];
```

You where checking the HTTP status code, but since the connection timed out there is not statuscode.